# Do we have an operation corresponding to the "find" of Matlab in Eigen library?

Tags: matlab, find, eigen

Eigen library is very useful for Numerical calculation and linear algebra (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page). These days, I have been using this library quite often for numerical calculation. But sometimes, I cannot find some operation existing in Matlab.

In Matlab, I use "find" command frequently to find out the indices of an array (or a matrix) satisfying the given condition. The following is an example:

```
>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

x =

     1     2     3     4     5

>> find(x > 3)

ans =

     4     5

>>
```

Are there any similar operation in Eigen? I looked at the Eigen Help website, but I could not find a similar method so far.

Also, in Eigen cheat sheet, find doesn't appear:
http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/AsciiQuickReference.txt

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I don't know a hack to do this with Eigen, but look at the answer from Rody Oldenhuis there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501926/implementing-the-matlab-find-function

Comment: There's also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249329/matlab-find-numpy-nonzero-idioms-for-eigen), but I'm not sure it's an exact duplicate.

Comment: Did beaker's link solve your problem?